# JS записать массив в объект

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

пол дня пытаюсь записать массив в объект, но корректно не получается.

Дано:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Требуется отделить четные от нечетных и вернуть объект вида:

```
{ even: [2, 4, 6], odd: [1, 3, 5] }
```

Что удалось сделать:

```
function separateArray(array) {
  var e = array.filter(i => i % 2 == 0); // получил массив с четными
  var o = array.filter(i => i % 2 !== 0); // получил массив с нечетными

  var oString = o.join(', '); //сделал строку из массива с нечетенми для примера

  var goal = new Object(); // сделал целевой объект
  goal.even = e; // значение ключа массив --- не отображается
  goal.odd = oString; // значение ключа строка --- отображается, но без квадраных скобок

  console.log(goal);
  alert(goal);
}
```

Результат сейчас:

```
{even: Array(3), odd: '1, 3, 5'}
```

Comment: Зачем вам `join()`, если хотите массив?

Comment: хочу ответ требуемого вида, а присвоить содержание массива в значение ключа объекта не придумал как

Comment: `goal.odd = o;`  не то?

Comment: Если проблема конкретно в отображении в консоли то напишите как сказал @АлексейШиманский и в консоль выведите не просто `goal`, а `JSON.stringify(goal)`

Answer (score -1):

**Например такой вариант**

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const separateArray = coll => {
  const result = {
    even: [],
    odd: []
  }

  coll.forEach(num => {
    num % 2 === 0 ? result.even.push(num) : result.odd.push(num)
  })

  return result;
}

console.log(separateArray(numbers));
```

Comment: У автора вопрос вполне рабочий вариант. За исключением одной строчки.

Comment: я просто предложил свое решение. Как мне кажется в разы проще

Comment: Дело не просто в простоте. Вы не объясняете почему ваш вариант лучше чем у автора. Почему ему надо использовать ваш код вместо своего. Ваш вариант ведь не единнственный простой способ решить задачу

Comment: @EzioMercer, Мне кажется вы передергиваете,   у функции одна задача, разбить числа на четные и нечетные. По одному и тому же шаблону  - всегда. Что мешает сразу  создать конструкцию шаблона  и просто аккумулировать данные.

Comment: Я разве сказал, что с вашим кодом что-то не так? Я говорю что, если вместо рабочего кода вопрошаещего вы предлагаете свой, то стоит объяснить, чем ваш лучше. Может вам проще, а ему тернарный оператор читать труднее? Но к примеру сказав, что вы проходитесь по массиву 1 раз место 2-х вы его чему-нибудь да и научите